# Append to window.open()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to open preview window with ability to confirm it, so I want to use window.open() and append some checkbox at bottom of document. I think it should be something like

```
var w = window.open("http://mypage.aspx", "_parent", "width=800,height=800");
w.document.write("<input type='checkbox' id='IsConfirmed' />");
```

but this code is not working... It doesn't load content of `http://mypage.aspx`.

So the question is how to load content of "http://mypage.aspx" and append checkbox at bottom of page?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't, don't use `document.write` in newly written code. And I can tell your code fails just because you used `document.write`. Use DOM manipulation instead.

Comment: That code is correct,you should check if you can load the page in the browser.

Comment: If the code would work (e.g. the page you loaded was from the same domain as the script), then the page would be wiped. You cannot do document.write after load, only inline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that `http://mypage.aspx` is a valid page path, it will take time to load so playing with the document right at the start might not be a good idea. It could also be why it does not seem to get loaded.

```
var w = window.open("http://mypage.aspx", "_parent", "width=800,height=800");
w.onload = function(){this.document.body.innerHTML+="<input type='checkbox' id='IsConfirmed' />";};
```

Using onload on the window will make sure that you are appending the checkbox after the page has been fully loaded... This will prevent some errors.

Comment: If you ever write after the page is loaded I believe you're going to overwrite the page. Also "appending" like this breaks the DOM.

Comment: using `.innerHTML` is still easy to break the DOM if you write something wrong. I think it's the best to stick with DOM manipulation (e.g. `document.createElement('input')`, `document.body.appendChild(elem)`)

Comment: I want to stay as close as possible to the original code. This way the answer is clearer to someone not too comfortable with JS. But you are right.

Answer (score 0):

http://mypage.aspx looks wrong... where's the hostname?

ok.. even if that request is valid.. the moment the request is fulfilled, the variable w is no longer available i think... You are on a different page and the javascript variables don't persist through a location change i think..

Comment: Sorry, I miss it at description, page address is valid.

Comment: well... 
i tried to fire an alert after a window.open like yours.. and the alert actually happens before the load. So you document.write.. or $(document.body).append(...) won't work...
and setting w.onload = whatever... the whatever doesn't seems to fire at all actually... 
because once the page is loaded into the parent frame... the javascript runtime is wiped.. so the listen's wiped before it can fire off