# appendChild doesn't work on new window using window.open()

Tags: javascript, dom, window.open, appendchild

I've got a problem with script that works well on when I run it on current tab but when I try to use it on other widow using `window.open` it doesn't work. The simplified version of code looks like this:

```
var win = window.open("some_url");
var new_element = win.document.createElement('div');
new_element.textContent = "some text";
win.document.head.appendChild(new_element);
```

Im using chrome snippet tester in dev tools and it works perfectly fine when i run this stript on current window. I know it doesn't work in new widow because inspecting doesn't show any new elements. Does anybody know why it won't work? I have zero knowledge about the order of DOM creation and so on. Maybe I can't append to it until its already loaded?

Comment: I think you are looking for something like this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34862451/append-content-to-new-browser-window-from-the-parent-page

Comment: Maybe DOM is not loaded yet on win, [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13008249/append-to-window-open)

Comment: both of your suggestions work only when the new window is "about:blank" when I open a window with some real url it does nothing

Comment: @quqa123 because this is a potential security-related risk which is blocked by most browsers. Is it on the same server/domain?

Answer (score 1):

After some digging I've finally got not a solution but an anwser. The reason why code did work on blank page but not on some real url's is because normally websites use Cross-site scripting blocks that are blocking such actions. So there was nothing wrong with the code. It was the site that was blocking it's execution.